# Navigation component with bottom nav bar not working

Tags: android, kotlin, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack-navigation

I'm trying to set up a navigation component with the bottom navbar. it is being set since I'm getting the fragment that has been set as home as the fragment. However it's not changing on pressing the other buttons.

**activity_main.xml**

```
<fragment
            android:id="@+id/fragNavHost"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:defaultNavHost="true"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/bottom_nav_graph" />
 <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/hide_bottom_view_on_scroll_behavior"
        style="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.BottomNavigationView"
        app:menu="@menu/menu"/>
```

**bottom_nav_graph.xml**

```
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav_graph.xml"
    app:startDestination="@id/homeFragment">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/homeFragment"
        android:name="com.example.testproject.HomeFragment"
        android:label="fragment_home"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_home" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/profileFragment"
        android:name="com.example.testproject.ProfileFragment"
        android:label="fragment_profile"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_profile" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/searchFragment"
        android:name="com.example.testproject.SearchFragment"
        android:label="fragment_search"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_search" />
</navigation>
```

and used it in the main activity like so.

```
        // Finding the Navigation Controller
        var navController = findNavController(R.id.fragNavHost)

        // Setting Navigation Controller with the BottomNavigationView
        bottomNavView.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

What am I doing wrong?

1. I have checked if the name of the fragment is the same as the id in the nav graph.

Edit: Solved. the name in my menu was different to the ids

Answer (score 4):

I execute below code in onCreate to get it working.

```
    val navHostFragment = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment) as NavHostFragment
    val navController = navHostFragment.navController
    bottomNavigation.setupWithNavController(navController)
```

Comment: Thank you i got it working. the name of my id's in the menu was different which was causing an issue . An upvote for helping..:)

Answer (score 0):

When using navigation controls, you need to use the navigate() method to navigate to the corresponding fragment

like this:

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_inputNetInfoFragment_to_inputMasterInfoFragment)
```

Comment: not really. I was trying to find a way to add my navigation component to the bottom bar and not navigate from one fragment to another.

Comment: I'm sorry, I misunderstood what you meant